# How to fetch players that connected to game in Android using Google game service?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have tried this code

```
Games.Players.loadMoreRecentlyPlayedWithPlayers(
                        mGoogleApiClient, 20);
```

but I'm not sure how to use it .

Comment: Elaborate your properly question to get valuable attention by developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my Answer by this i can fetch My recent Game Players.

```
PendingResult<Players.LoadPlayersResult> loadplayers = Games.Players
         .loadMoreRecentlyPlayedWithPlayers(mGoogleApiClient, 20);
loadplayers.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Players.LoadPlayersResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPlayersResult loadplayersResult) {

        if (loadplayersResult != null) {
            if (loadplayersResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
                if (loadplayersResult.getPlayers() != null) {
                    PlayerBuffer plyersBufr = loadplayersResult.getPlayers();
                    for (Player p : plyersBufr) {
                        Log.d(TAG, p.getDisplayName() + "  " + p.getTitle()+"  "
                                    + p.getLastPlayedWithTimestamp() + "  " + p.getLevelInfo());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

anyway thanks :)